# Ruby Gosu crash error: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libgosu

```
def update
        if button_down?(Gosu::KB_SPACE) && !@pressed
            @y -= 30
            @pressed = true
        elsif !button_down?(Gosu::KB_SPACE)
            @pressed = false
        end
        if @vel.nil?
            @vel *= 4
            @y += @vel * 0.05
        end
    end
```

everytime i add an operator for @vel it gives me this error. Why's that?

tried checking if the variable is nil to run but none worked for me

Comment: `if @vel.nil?` : everything after that runs only if @vel equals nil. You then proceed by `@vel *= 4`, which does not work. `nil*4` - what is the result you expect? Did you mean `unless @vel.nil?`

Answer (score 0):

The conditional `@vel.nil?` only returns true when `@vel` is `nil`. You want the opposite, either use `!@vel.nil?` or use the `unless` keyword instead of the `if` keyword before `@vel.nil?`.